# get specify array in curl

Tags: php, arrays, curl

i get some data with curl from web service
and here is my curl code:

```
$uri="http://test.com";
$ch=curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('shopid:691','device:2'),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true
));
$out=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj=json_decode($out,true);
print_r($obj);
```

and my curl out put:

```
{
  "p":
    "Serial": "b216"
  },
  "review": {
    "Review": "<div dir=\"rtl\">test</div>\r\n"
  },
  "likes": 2,
  "brand": {
    "Name": "test"
  },
  "followers": [],
  "Shop": null
}
```

i want to get "b216" value in array "p"
but i cannot get the value with print_r or
echo $obj[0] or 
echo $obj[0]['Serial']

anyone know how to get this data?

Comment: Is that your cURL output or your `print_r` output?

Comment: my curl output.

Comment: Then (logically) your `print_r($obj)`  output should  be of an array which you could do `$obj["p"]["Serial"]`

Comment: thank you very much its work:))))))))))))